# Different ways to produce the same network in NEAT

Tags: neat, neuroevolution

I have an interesting example for the NEAT and want to clarify what behavior is correct from NEAT's perspective and **why** (why the opposite is wrong, what are the consequences of choosing the different one).

So let we have an initial network of 3 nodes and 2 edges:

### Initial Condition

```
Nodes: [A, B, C]
Edges: {
1: A->B
2: B->C
}
```

---

### 1st Gen

Then in the 1-st generation we get 2 mutants:

##### Mutant 1 (edge 1 got split)

```
Nodes: [A, B, C, D]
Edges: {
1: A->B DIS
2: B->C
3: A->D
4: D->B
}
```

##### Mutant 2 (edge 2 got split)

```
Nodes: [A, B, C, E]
Edges: {
1: A->B
2: B->C DIS
5: B->E
6: E->C
}
```

---

### 2nd Gen

In the second generation 2 if we mutate Mutant 1 (by splitting edge 2) and mutate Mutant 2 (by splitting edge 1) which result should we get?

##### Hypothesis 1: the same result:

```
Nodes: [A, B, C, D, E]
Edges: {
1: A->B DIS
2: B->C DIS
3: A->D
4: D->B
5: B->E
6: E->C
}
```

#### or...

##### Hypothesis 2: Two new mutants:

```
Nodes: [A, B, C, D, F]
Edges: {
1: A->B DIS
2: B->C DIS
3: A->D
4: D->B
7: B->F
8: F->C
}
```

and

```
Nodes: [A, B, C, E, G]
Edges: {
1: A->B DIS
2: B->C DIS
5: B->E
6: E->C
9: A->G
10: G->B
}
```

---

In case the second hypothesis is correct, how does it deal with crossover in the next run?
Say these 2 mutants are breeded. We get :

##### Breeding in 2nd Hypothesis

```
Nodes: [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
Edges: {
1: A->B DIS
2: B->C DIS
3: A->D
4: D->B
5: B->E
6: E->C
7: B->F
8: F->C
9: A->G
10: G->B
}
```

Looks like a too complicated genome for the 3-rd generation, doesn't it?

*In case the first option is correct then actually innovation numbers are somewhat redundant in NEAT and can be done differently.
We can have node list as a list of strings (node names).
Then instead of assigning the innovation number to an edge we can use string value calculated like `HASH(fromNodeName + toNodeName)`.
That way whenever the new link is created in any generation between 2 nodes it gets the same innovation <strike>number</strike> name for it.
When the node is created (by splitting an edge) its name can be taken right from the edge getting split and the innovation names of 2 new edges can be calculated like `HASH(fromNodeName + splitEdgeName)` and `HASH(splitEdgeName + toNodeName)`.
That way the algorithm has no global variables, no shared list of all innovations and can be simply parallelized*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's first draw the network in each case, for better visualizing the problem:

```
Initial:
┌─┐
│A│
└┬┘
┌▽┐
│B│
└┬┘
┌▽┐
│C│
└─┘
```

#### 1st Generation:

```
1st Gen
Mutation #1   Mutation #2
┌────┐        ┌────┐
│A   │        │A   │
└┬──┬┘        └┬───┘
┌▽┐ ┆         ┌▽───┐
│D│ ┆DIS      │B   │
└┬┘ ┆         └┬──┬┘
┌▽───┐        ┌▽┐ ┆
│ B  │        │E│ ┆DIS
└┬───┘        └┬┘ ┆
┌▽───┐        ┌▽───┐
│ C  │        │ C  │
└────┘        └────┘
```

#### 2nd Generation

```
1st Hypothesis (Same Result)
┌────┐
│A   │
└┬──┬┘
 ┆ ┌▽┐
DIS│D│
 ┆ └┬┘
┌───▽┐
│B   │
└┬──┬┘
 ┆ ┌▽┐
DIS│E│
 ┆ └┬┘
┌───▽┐
│C   │
└────┘
```

In order to converge the 2 mutations like this, we would need to:

- Somehow make topology accessible globally.
- Make one mutation search for the population, looking for an occurrence of a similar split.

Both items go against the principle of evolution, as only 2 mating individuals should trade genetic information.

```
2nd Hypothesis (Two Mutants)
┌────┐   ┌────┐
│A   │   │A   │
└┬──┬┘   └┬──┬┘
 ┆ ┌▽┐    ┆ ┌▽┐
DIS│D│   DIS│G│
 ┆ └┬┘    ┆ └┬┘
┌───▽┐   ┌───▽┐
│B   │   │B   │
└┬──┬┘   └┬──┬┘
 ┆ ┌▽┐    ┆ ┌▽┐
DIS│F│   DIS│E│
 ┆ └┬┘    ┆ └┬┘
┌───▽┐   ┌───▽┐
│C   │   │C   │
└────┘   └────┘
```

Yes. This 2nd approach is the most usual. Each mutation generates a completely new gene.

```
┌────┐
│A   │
└┬──┬┘
┌▽┐┌▽┐
│8││D│
└─┘└┬┘
┌───▽┐
│B   │
└┬──┬┘
┌▽┐┌▽┐
│u││F│
└─┘└┬┘
┌───▽┐
│C   │
└────┘
```

---

> Looks like a too complicated genome for the 3-rd generation, doesn't it?

And yes. A 3rd generation **could** theoretically come up like this complicated genome.[1]

```
┌───────┐
│A      │
└┬──┬──┬┘
┌▽┐┌▽┐ ┆
│G││D│DIS
└┬┘└┬┘ ┆ 
┌▽──▽───┐
│B      │
└┬──┬──┬┘
┌▽┐┌▽┐ ┆ 
│F││E│DIS
└┬┘└┬┘ ┆
┌▽──▽───┐   
│C      │   
└───────┘
```

But keep in mind that more complex structures are naturally harder to train and therefore will not survive if the performance does not justify the complexity.

[1] - Usually disjoint genes and excess genes (those that do not match) are chosen from the fittest parent. However, in (very specific) cases where 2 parents have the same fit, it could be chosen randomly.

Main source: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.5457&rep=rep1&type=pdf

---

In the end, you propose an interesting method, to use hashes instead of integers for identifying genes. This is a bold suggestion, and I'm not an expert, so *this part is mostly opinionated*:

I believe original genes numeration idea is:

- Inspired on the natural genes sequencing
- For assuring uniqueness genes identifications
- And tracking history changes, just like Git.

But it could also work using a hash.

On one side, that could be a great feature, for allowing distant relatives to breed with consistency.
On the other side, distant relatives tend to have a very different structure and the gene might not be so relevant to them.

I encourage you to test it. And if it works better than the vanilla, you should release a paper!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Specifically 'tracking history changes, just like Git' was what inspired me to think about hashes :) What really changes with hash-based approach is what genes are the same. In my approach more genes are treated as the same (as you see in hypothesis 1). Definitely I have to test both approaches now, I will put results here for you (but do not expect I will do it quickly - it is just a hobby for me)

Comment: Great! I have no previous academic experience on Machine Learning, but if you want to publish a paper and want some help, I think I could join you. Anyway, I'm excited to see the results! :)